# Wie kam das 'e' in den "Schmied"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history, spelling

Schon länger frage ich mich, wie es zur Dehnung des "i"-Vokals und zur Bildung eines "-ie-" in der Berufsbezeichnung "[Schmied](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmied)" kam.

Im Duden, aber auch in anderen Wörterbüchern ist die Herkunft aus dem althochdeutschen **smid** und dem mittelhochdeutschen **smit** belegt. Auch in anderen Sprachen findet sich bis heute die Schreibung mit nur einem "i", z.B. *smith* (Engl.).

In Familiennamen blieb aber die alte Schreibung erhalten (Schmid, Schmidt, Schmitt) und kommt somit wesentlich häufiger vor, als der Beruf Schmied:

[image]

<sup>[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Schmid,Schmied,Schmidt,Schmitt&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Schmid;,c0;.t1;,Schmied;,c0;.t1;,Schmidt;,c0;.t1;,Schmitt;,c0)</sup>

Gibt es Belege, ab wann eine Dehnung des Vokals erfolgte? Oder war das "i" schon immer gedehnt und es wurde irgendwann die Orthografie daran angepasst?

Comment: Jedenfalls dürfte eindeutig sein, dass die Festlegung der Schreibweise des Berufes nicht zur Folge hat, dass die Familiennamen sich daran anpassen.

Comment: Angenommen, dass "i" wäre schon immer gedehnt gewesen, so wäre ja vor allen Dingen auch der Familienname angepasst worden. Das einerseits der Beruf ein Dehungs-e erhält und gleichzeitig die Aussprache des Familienname sich ändert, halte ich für sehr unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Ich würde mal denken, das war einfach um es vom Familiennamen abzugrenzen, denn irgendwann gab es dann einfach zu viele Schidts die nicht Schmied waren. Dann hat man's ortograpihisch getrennt und das hat dann die Aussprache vereinheitlicht.

Comment: Andererseits, kein zweiter Name hat so viele Varianten. Schmidt, Schmitt, Schmid, Schmitz und noch ein paar weitere...

Comment: @Em1: Es war auch ein recht verbreiteter und ausserdem angesehener Beruf. Für Müller oder Meier gibt es die Schreibweisen auch im Dutzend.

Comment: @Emanuel Dagegen spricht, dass es den Familiennamen "Schmied" auch gibt, wenngleich auch seltener im Vergleich zu den anderen Formen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Schreibung von *Schmied* mit *ie* geht wohl laut Grimms Wörterbuch auf den Beginn des 19. Jahrhunderts zurück:

> "... die ursprüngliche kürze des stammvocals von schmied erscheint im früheren nhd. durchgehends gewahrt. Maaler 358a, Hulsius 286b, Schottel 1404, Stieler 1879 und Wachter 1443 bieten schmid, Frisch 2, 208a daneben auch schmied, das er für die ältere, eigentliche form hält. nach Adelung sollte der sing. schmid, der plur. schmiede geschrieben werden, weil der erste kurzen, der letztere langen vocal habe. auf flectierte und unflectierte form bezogen hat diese unterscheidung historische berechtigung, weil inlautende media im nhd. längung des stammvocals im gefolge hat, während sie im auslaut zur tenuis verschärft meist alte kürze erhält (tăc — tāges). Campe will die länge des vocals und demgemäsz die schreibung mit ie, die auch Steinbach 2, 464 schon in unflectierter form gewährt, überall durchgeführt wissen, und diese regelung hat, wenigstens was die schreibung anbelangt, heute allgemeine geltung. die aussprache schwankt zwischen schmĭd und schmīd, während sie natürlich bei schmiedes, schmiede als lang feststeht. ..." [<sup>(1)</sup>](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS13754)

Demnach wurde die heutige Schreibung nach [J.H.Campe](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Campe) geregelt, der dazu in seinem Wörterbuch folgendes anmerkte:

[image: http://books.google.de/books?id=A_09AQAAMAAJ&dq=campe%20%22w%C3%B6rterbuch%20der%20deutschen%20sprache%22%20schmidt&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=schmied&f=false]

> "... Ränkeschmied. - Der erste Fall der Schmied wird zwar in O.S. so wie in N.D. geschärft, daher Ad. Schmid schreibt; allein in andern Gegenden ist auch der erste Fall mit Recht gedehnt so wie alle übrige Fälle und die von Schmied und Schmieden abgeleiteten und damit zusammengesetzten Wörter. So scheint also eine Sonderbarkeit zu sein, bloß diesen ersten Fall geschärft auszusprechen und dem gemäß Schmid zu schreiben. ..." [<sup>(2)</sup>](http://books.google.de/books?id=A_09AQAAMAAJ&dq=campe%20%22w%C3%B6rterbuch%20der%20deutschen%20sprache%22%20schmidt&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=schmied&f=false) (Anmerkung: N.D.=Niederdeutschland, Ad.=Adelung, geschärft=kurz)

Im Mündlichen durchgesetzt hatte sich der lange Vokal in *Schmied* nach einem anfänglichen Nord-Süd-Gefälle, heute noch ersichtlich an den regional auf Gebiete geballten Namensvorkommen, die aus der Berufsbezeichnung entstanden [<sup>(3)</sup>](http://www.allemagne-au-max.com/forum/schmidt-schmitz-schmid-schmitt-vt11129.html):

- *Schmid* (Süden, langer Vokal)
- *Schmidt*, *Schmitz* (Norden, kurzer Vokal).

Comment: das war mal wieder eine gute Leseübung von alter Schrift ;)

Comment: ja, aber nur da steht es :)